# script to read from a text file and create config files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file called `lists.txt` which has all the nodes listed in it. The file is in `/etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/` and has this content:

```
node1
node2
node3
.
.
.
```

I also have another file called `template.conf`

I would like to write a script that

1. Reads from `lists.txt` file
2. Createds a new conf file with the node name by copying the content of the `template.conf` as `node1.conf`
3. Creates a new directory called new: `/etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new`
4. `chmod icinga:icinga node1.conf`
5. git add node1.conf

This is what I came up with so far:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/
mkdir new
chown -R icinga:icinga new

for f in list.txt
do 
   cp -v "$f" /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new/"${f%.conf}"
done
cp template.conf ${f%.conf}
chmod icinga:icinga ${f%.conf}
git add ${f%.conf}
```

would you please help me complete it? Thanks in advance

---

@william-pursell,
Thanks for your reply. This is the script, it runs and throws some errors but the file do get created but without the .conf suffix:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new
while read f; do
   cp -v "$f" /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new/"${f%}.conf"
   cp template.conf "${f%.conf}"
   chown icinga:icinga "${f%}.conf"
#   git add "${f%.conf}"
#   git commit -m "Add $f"
done < list.txt
```

It runs and creates new files called node1, node2, ... without the suffix .conf though. Not sure why. Then copies the contents of the template in all of them but also throws these errors:

`cp: cannot stat ‘node1’: No such file or directory chown: cannot access ‘node2’: No such file or directory`

I tried to add this as a comment but the formatting made it unreadable.

Thank you

Comment: so where does your program fail? You seem to have coded every feature you needed!

Comment: Take a look at this [Bash FAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) explaining how to read a file line by line. Try to implement it and use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to assist you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
while read f; do 
   cp -v "$f" /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new/"${f%.conf}"
   cp template.conf "${f%.conf}"
   chmod icinga:icinga "${f%.conf}"
   git add "${f%.conf}"
   git commit -m "Add $f"
done < list.txt
```

Note that this will utterly fail if any of your file names contain a newline, but that scenario doesn't really work well if you're storing the filenames in a file one per line.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
This is the final script, it runs and creates new files called node1, node2, ... without the suffix .conf though. Not sure why.

Then copies the contents of the template in all of them but also throws these errors:

[CODE]
cp: cannot stat ‘node1’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access ‘node2’: No such file or directory
[/CODE]

Comment: `code` #!/bin/bash
cd /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new
while read f; do
   cp -v "$f" /etc/icinga2/zones.d/master/hosts/new/"${f%}.conf"
   cp template.conf "${f%.conf}"
   chown icinga:icinga "${f%}.conf"
#   git add "${f%.conf}"
#   git commit -m "Add $f"
done < list.txt
`code`

Comment: The `.conf` suffix is missing because you explicitly remove it with `${f%.conf}`